# How to add or remove array item in windows phone?

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-parsing, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml, listbox-control

Hi am using xaml file and code given below. I want to get two categories one is current categories and other one is removed categories.If i remove one category it should go to add current category.I don't have any idea about this.so please can any one tell me how to resolve this issue.

```
<StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="Current categories"
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>

       <ListBox x:Name="AddingList" ItemsSource="{Binding name}" SelectionChanged="AddingList_SelectionChanged_1"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Removed categories"
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />

        <ListBox x:Name="RemoveList" ItemsSource="{Binding name}" SelectionChanged="RemoveList_SelectionChanged_1"/>

 </StackPanel>
```

my xaml.cs code

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/CategoriesPage.xaml?" + NotchsList11, UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

I am using edit button, How can i pass listbox item from edit button to categories page and how remove and add listbox items.

My out put want given below image so please help me some one
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few ways of going about this. 
One way is to have a single object that has "isRemoved" boolean on it that you just turn on and off. Another way is you could have 2 observablecollections one holding the added, and one holding the removed. so for example:

class:

```
public class MyData
{
    public bool isRemoved { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Use:

```
ObservableCollection<MyData> AllData = new ObservableCollection<MyData>()
AllData.Add(new MyData(){ isRemoved = true, Name = "Data1"}
AllData.Add(new MyData(){ isRemoved = true, Name = "Data2"}
AllData.Add(new MyData(){ isRemoved = false, Name = "Data3"}

AddingList.ItemsSource = AllData.Where(srch => srch.isRemoved == false);
RemoveList.ItemsSource = AllData.Where(srch => srch.isRemoved == true);
```

In your Remove button click you just set the isRemoved to true  and in your Add you set the isRemoved to false.

or you could use 2 ObservableCollections adding and removing from each.

Comment: Hi @Wigen i have used two observation collection but how can i get listbox value from main page

Comment: I dont know if i quite understand the question? Are you asking how you get the listbox item when you click the add or remove? if so, you can check the datacontext of the button selected.

Comment: Not like that,I have edit button, if i click edit button it should go to categories page and show add or remove categories item and then if i click current item it should go to add item again if i click add item it should go to current item. this is requirement.so how to pass data with edit button on categories page and how to show all list items?